Regexextract() capturing group not working in Google Sheets?
I would really appreciate another set of eyes to tell me why this capture group is not working.
=REGEXREPLACE(A2," ([\w\/ ]+)$", "$1")
I want to grab the last "word" after a "-" (it is a folder path structure).
Here is what I am getting:
Path                                     Final FolderName
Orders - Colonoscopy - Death Certificate
                                         Orders - Colonoscopy -Death Certificate

Orders - Colonoscopy - Death Certificate - Advance Directive    
                                         Orders - Colonoscopy - Death Certificate -Advance Directive

Orders - Colonoscopy                     Orders -Colonoscopy
Patient Records - Radiology          Patient Records -Radiology


When I want to be getting:
                                         Death Certificate
                                         Advance Directive
                                         Colonoscopy
                                         Radiology

I know that I have been able to do this type of thing before in Google Sheets.

I did find a solution that will work for me, but I don't understand why this approach with
RegexReplace()  and capturing groups isn't working.

What does work is:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A17,"([^ -][A-Za-z'\/ ]+)$")


You can simply use:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+- (.+)") 


Thank you.  I make this mistake a lot with regular expressions and capturing groups...
I don't include the  ".+" or ".*" before or after the capturing group to allow the pattern to match in the first place.

A non-regex alternative is;
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",255)),255))

where cell A1 is housing the original string
